# Is it possible to limit the formatting of a string in Typescript (or ESLint?)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, styled-components

I'm working in a codebase using React (CRA) and TypeScript. We've got the typical settings with a few linters and our own Design System.

Recently, we updated the Design System with CSS in JS, to allow the use of props like `width="125px"` on any components coming from it. We also introduced a Sizing and Spacing scales, which allows to use `width={8}` (for example).

While we're trying our best to share the knowledge within the company, I'm seeing some code changes including changes like `width="8"` (it does make sense that if you're not used to it, a number as prop will usually be set as a string, and you would keep the `{}` only for actual variables and objects). This still works and outputs the right value in the HTML, but it takes away the validation within the editor (`width={30}` would be out of our scale and the dev would be notified, `width="30"` is just a string so we're not checking it).

So TLDR, my question is: Is it possible to type check more aggressively but also in a smart way. My goal would be to:

- Allow: `{10}` `"10px"` `"10rem"` `"10%"` `"inherit"` etc.
- Deny: `"10"`
- Allow `"10"` on other props like `line-height` or `font-weight` (typed separately so I don't even think this needs to be changed)

Right now, if I take `width` for example, the typing is using our own scale going from `{1}` to `{18}`:

```
  export type Width<TLength = (string & {}) | 0> =
| Globals
| TLength
| "-moz-fit-content"
| "-moz-max-content"
| "-moz-min-content"
| "-webkit-fit-content"
| "-webkit-max-content"
| "auto"
| "fit-content"
| "intrinsic"
| "max-content"
| "min-content"
| "min-intrinsic"
| (string & {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) (tsc >=4.1)

```js
type Nums = 1 | 2 | 3;

type Unit = "px" | "em" | "%";
type NumWithUnit = `${number}${Unit}`

type Width = Nums | NumWithUnit | "inherit"

const passes: Width[] = [
  1, 2, 3,
  "10px",
  "1.5em",
  "50%",
  "inherit"
]

const fails: Width[] = [
  // @ts-expect-error
  4,
  // @ts-expect-error
  "10",
  // @ts-expect-error
  "x em"
]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwM5QLxQIxQD5QEw5QDMA3AFBmiRQCqAdgJbBpQBEYAHq4axAt7lYBSVuSrR4CAOpMAFvSYsABgBIA3nUQAjCACcAvuoXB9SiuKgyAJsFktJKXJJm3jPBnVl6mrCgGMAezokZjAAQyQkCCQALksGG1kAbQBdFiSyKEwAGnxcomzMtgwABk5WQqzWDAA6AFY%20CqLWOpKRSrYPL10fMhT-IJCoADMwhgAbWPjE1PSigHp5qAABYCQAWggOSD9gTd1dAN0igBYOxZW1ze2IXf3D46rSpqyL1Y2tnb29B%20aOKEafSAA)